# ElasticSearch.NET and F# Issue w/ Query

Tags: elasticsearch, f#, c#-to-f#, elasticsearch-net

I am attempting to convert a C# codebase over to F# that uses ElasticSearch.NET client. F# seems to not properly infer the correct types.

Here is the working C# code:

```
var res = es.Search<Question>(s => s
   .Query(q => q
   .FunctionScore(fs => fs
   .Query(fq => fq.MatchAll())
   .Functions(f => f.RandomScore(r.Next()))
)).Size(count).Index("questions"));
```

The equivalent or matching F# code is below and it doesn't compile:

```
    let questions = es.Search<Question>(fun s ->
                    s.Query(fun q -> q.FunctionScore(
                                        fun fs -> fs.Query(
                                                    fun fq->fq.MatchAll()).Functions(
                                                            fun f -> f.RandomScore(r.Next())) |> ignore)).Size(count).Index("questions")).Documents.ToList()
```

This code does properly work using F#, however, it's not what I need:

```
let questions2 = es.Search<Question>(fun s -> s.Query(fun q -> q.MatchAll())).Documents.ToList()
```

The F# that does not compile shows the following error:

> Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to
>   this program. A type annotation may be required prior to this program
>   point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup
>   to be resolved.

The F# type signature of Question follows:

```
type Question = {id:Guid, Text:string}
```

Comment: So add a type annotation

Comment: Done that as well, doesn't work.

Comment: Show what you've done, show what the error is after that.

Comment: It's not trivial to reproduce this.  I am unfamiliar with ElasticSearch.NET.  Could you show declaration and/or type of local variable es

Comment: Looking at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MartinBodocky/9704c9c697313887297b), it doesn't look like it's trivial to use the .NET client's query builder extension methods in F#. [Building a raw query or using `QueryContainer`](https://www.codesuji.com/2018/10/10/F-and-Elasticsearch/) looks simpler.